# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: u

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created a method to get user count. This is my `JPARepository`. But I am getting `QuerySyntaxException`. I do not know how to solve this.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from User u where u.usertype is NULL u.country=?1 and u.state=?2 and u.city=?3 and u.datasource=?4")
int getusercount();
```

But When I run the code, I got:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: u near line 1, column 78 [SELECT COUNT(*) from User u where u.usertype is NULL u.country=?1 and u.state=?2 and u.city=?3 and u.datasource=?4]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
atorg.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
atorg.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
atorg.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you forgot to add an `and` operator in your query after the first condition. The query should be like

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) from User u where u.usertype is NULL and u.country=?1 and u.state=?2 and u.city=?3 and u.datasource=?4")
```

The exception `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException` is self explanatory that there is a syntax error in the query. It says `unexpected token: u near line 1, column 78` means that after the condition `u.usertype in NULL` it expects some operator or some other sql keyword such as order by etc but instead it has u.country which is unexpected.

Comment: && operator or AND operator? Because I have written and in every condition that I have used here.

Comment: AND operator. Its not case sensitive so using `and` is same as AND